# Measuring the limit of a point on a smooth.spline in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I'm not sure if that's the right terminology.

I've entered some data into R, and I've put a smooth.spline through it using the following command.

```
smoothingSpline = smooth.spline(year, rate, spar=0.35)
plot(x,y)
lines(smoothingSpline)
```

Now I'd like to measure some limits (or where the curve is at a given x point), and maybe do some predictive analysis on points that extend beyond the graph.

Are there commands in R for measuring (or predicting) the points along a curve?

Comment: Use uniroot() to invert the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `?predict.smooth.spline` what you are looking for?

Comment: doubt it; that will predict `y` given `x`. The OP asks for a given `t` point, but that may be typo.

Comment: I'm not sure. I just tried it and wasn't able to get it to work. I may have been using it wrong. The documentation is unclear. I'm going to try using a loess line instead with predict.loess. That might be easier to use.

Comment: Predicting x from y might not give a unique value or am I missing something here?

Comment: I just want to put a curve through some data, and measure different points along that curve, and beyond the graph. I think it's a "regression" problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: So this is the case where you don't know which tool to use for the job and maybe even don't know what the job actually is? People might be able to help you with more information (e.g., given some data and background information).

Comment: I know what the job is. I'm just unfamiliar with the terminology. I can explain it in calculus terms. I want to measure the limits along the curve. But I don't know how to say this in "R."

Comment: My maths lectures were not in English. Please excuse my question: What is the definition of "limits along the curve"?

Comment: [Limits Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)). But I've made some progress. predict(smoothingSpline,year,deriv=0) has given me some results.